# Left-side cosets of an open subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H$ its closed subgroup. $K$ and $L$ are open subgroups of $G$ and $H$ respectively. Let $g_{1}, g_{2}\in G$. We assume $L\cap g_{1}K\neq \emptyset$ and $L\cap g_{2}K\neq \emptyset$. Then is there an element $x\in H$ (also $x\in L$) such that $L\cap g_{1}K=x(L\cap g_{2}K)$ ?

Comment: The question makes when $G$ is discrete, and trivially a positive answer in the discrete case implies a positive answer in general (just use the underlying group with the discrete topology). Hence, it's just a question about abstract groups.

Comment: There exist $k_{1}, k_{2}\in K$ such that $g_{1}k_{1}, g_{2}k_{2}\in L$. Then $L\cap g_{i}K=g_{i}k_{i}(L\cap K), (i=1, 2)$ are both left cosets of $L\cap K$ in $L$. So I could take $x\in L$ such I needed in my Question.